# Fighting robot spam different way

Tags: javascript, validation, bots, spam-prevention

I have a website with simple form that posts input as tweets to a twitter account.

There is no captcha or any kind of anti-spam system installed, so it's only logical that spam-bots have been posting their bogus content like crazy.

Now, I want to build a validation that does not require any sort of captcha.

This is what I've been thinking and I need your honest opinion.

If robots are posting their stuff without using mouse or keyboard (probably by using some sort of generated script), then that actually means that they cannot give any sort of focus to the form itself.

My idea is to create a simple js condition that the form cannot be submitted without gaining some sort of focus.

What do you think about this?
Any other sort of similar ideas?

Comment: If you don't load javascript at all, will it work? Because bots probably don't load js.

Comment: Me thinks it's a bad idea, as POST requests can be sent directly with Perl, cURL, Python, whatever, bypassing your form completely and sending the data directly to the server as POST request.

Comment: I agree. Please read the answer bellow and featured comments :)

Answer (score 3):

An idea of tweeting messages that have not been validated sounds pretty unsecured on its own. Still, there are a few ways to *minimize* the spam.

For instance, you could implement a [honeypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29) variation that adds another field to the submission form, but in a manner that's hidden from a live user. The bot would mistakenly fill it out and you could decline the submission on the server-side - believe it or not, most comment spam comes from crawlers, so even a basic approach like this could drastically decrease the amount of malicious content submitted.

You are correct in your assumption that most robots post *"without using mouse or keyboard"* - it is much more trivial to do so than to simulate client-side activity. Again, you could use this to your advantage - add a field that would be JS-populated and validate its content on the server-side.

Comment: Further more, use a hidden input field with multiple `data-` attributes as numbers (eg data-num1="7" data-num2="5") then user javascript to add these numbers together and populate the value of the hidden input. When validating, if the input is anything other than the total of the two numbers, then probably spam.

Comment: An interesting idea, I already did a similar thing a while ago.
Basically I can implement the js that fills the hidden field with unimportant string, and submits the form only if the hidden field has that value. Otherwise, it won't get submitted.
How about that?

Comment: OR, use javascript to add a hidden input field after 5 seconds? If the field is missing, then spam.

Comment: Awesome, few seconds before me :)

Comment: The issue with using JS or any other unobtrusive technique (recaptcha *is* oh-so-obtrusive) is that if someone *really* wants to target your site, they probably will succeed. Any logic executed on the client-side would be exposed to being simulated by the malicious script